# yum upgrade goes back to prompt right after "Determining fastest mirrors"

Tags: centos, yum

I am trying to run yum upgrade on a server,  it does virtually nothing...

```
[myusername@server-1 ~]$ sudo yum upgrade
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Upgrade Process
Determining fastest mirrors
[myusername@server-1 ~]$ █
```

I tried turning off the fastestmirror plugin and get this...

```
[myusername@server-1 ~]$ sudo yum upgrade
Freeing read locks for locker 0xXXXX: XXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Freeing read locks for locker 0xXXXX: XXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Setting up Upgrade Process
base                                                                 | 3.7 kB     00:00
```

(replaced actual numbers with X just in case here)

I tried rebooting.  Same problem after reboot.

The server has plenty of spare ram and free disk space.

It is a rackspace server.

**Edit:**  Output when using the verbose flag...

```
[myusername@server-1 yum.repos.d]$ sudo yum upgrade -v
Freeing read locks for locker 0xXXXX: XXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Freeing read locks for locker 0xXXXX: XXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Config time: 0.010
Yum Version: 3.2.29
rpmdb time: 0.000
Setting up Upgrade Process
Updating Everything
Building updates object
Setting up Package Sacks
Determining fastest mirrors
[myusername@server-1 yum.repos.d]$
```

Comment: Do you have outgoing network from that machine?  Notably to the URLs inside `/etc/yum.repos.d/`

Comment: Can you show us the output when you add the verbose flag?

Comment: @grochmal I can ping them (or the ones I tried) and other sites from the server.

Comment: By any chance, do you have `enabled=0` in all repos in `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` ?  You can set that to `enabled=1`.  Also, you can comment out `mirrorlist=` and uncomment `baseurl=`; that would pass through a firewall that drops URL queries.

Comment: Some of them had enabled=0 but not all (and presumably not the ones that matter)   Anyway today I reset my root password, then tried after 'su',  then got an extra error - 'illegal instruction'  I've posted an answer to my question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

I ran 'su'   then got slightly more info -

> Illegal instruction

I then googled this.  Found this page - https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=58002

Ran this command -

```
NSS_DISABLE_HW_GCM=1 yum upgrade
```

And the update process worked.

From that link...

> I think the actual problem is that the cpuinfo says it has AES but
>   when the system tries to use it, it discovers the support is not there
>   - hence the illegal instruction crash. Have you for example booted this guest on a host machine that has aes-ni and then migrated to one
>   that hasn't? Or overridden the processor type reported to the guest in
>   some way?
>
> You could use temporary fix of this problem, by setting the
>   environment variable: "NSS_DISABLE_HW_GCM=1"
>
> So for example if you run: NSS_DISABLE_HW_GCM=1 yum search
>   some_package ...